# Grafana executable not working - error file not found

Tags: docker, dockerfile, grafana, alpine-linux, system-administration

I am on Alpine Linux and am trying to launch grafana. I downloaded it using the following commands:

```
wget https://dl.grafana.com/oss/release/grafana-7.3.7.linux-amd64.tar.gz
tar -zxvf grafana-7.3.7.linux-amd64.tar.gz
mv grafana-7.3.7 grafana
```

When I try to run the executable `./grafana/bin/grafana-server` it shows the error:
`sh: ./grafana/bin/grafana-server: not found`

I don't understand why, if my config is wrong, it should at least show another error than "file not found".

Comment: Nevermind, I found the solution.
I needed to create a /lib64 folder where I copy "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" from the /lib folder. The executable searches /lib64 instead of /lib for its libraries

Comment: If you're having odd C-library-infrastructure issues like this, you may find a Debian- or Ubuntu-based image a better starting point.  Alpine uses an unusual library setup, and _many_ things will work with it, but it's not 100% seamless.

Answer (score 1):

Grafana requires `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. However Alpine doesn't have this dynamic library. You need to install [libc6-compat](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=ld-linux-x86-64.so.2&name=&branch=edge).

`ldd` let you know which library grafana needs.

```
ldd /grafana/bin/grafana-server
```

How to install `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`

```
apk add libc6-compat
```

or

```
apk update && apk add
```